# Weird elements in code that appears to be HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm currently modding a game and everything works fine when I use basic commands & attributes for formation etc. but there are some elements that I can't identify and modify as I would like.

Hopefuly someone can help me out, here's the code, elements in question follow

```
tr "game_spell_tooltip_EkkoQ" = "<titleLeft>Timewinder</titleLeft><titleRight>Level @Level@ [@Hotkey@]</titleRight><subtitleLeft>@Cost@ Mana</subtitleLeft><subtitleRight>@Cooldown@ sec Cooldown</subtitleRight><mainText>Ekko throws a device that deals @Effect1Amount@ <font color='#99FF99'>(+@CharAbilityPower@)</font> magic damage to enemies it passes through. It expands into a slowing field on the first champion hit, slowing everything inside by @Effect2Amount@%. It then returns to him after a delay, dealing @Effect3Amount@ <font color='#99FF99'>(+@CharAbilityPower2@)</font> magic damage to all targets hit upon return.</mainText>"
```

The elements in question are `<titleLeft>, <titleRight>` and the same for the subtitle elements

I've tried to implement another title in the center, both `<titleCenter>, <titleMiddle>` and simply `<title>` won't work, it just doesn't show up

Any other modifications like `<br>` and basic formation attributes work perfectly fine, but those are in the maintext

An example of my experimental slaughtery here

```
tr "game_spell_tooltip_EkkoE" = "<titleLeft>Phase Dive</titleLeft><titleRight>Level @Level@ [@Hotkey@]</titleRight><subtitleLeft>@Cost@ Mana</subtitleLeft><subtitleMiddle><font color='#F5E5D4'; size='2'><i>Dash & Teleport</i></font></subtitleMiddle><subtitleRight>@Cooldown@ sec Cooldown</subtitleRight><mainText><font color='#7C03FC'>Magic Damage: @Effect1Amount@</font> <font color='#99FF99'>(+@CharAbilityPower@)</font></mainText>"
```

The subtitleCenter doesn't work either.

Any ideas?

Best regards

Comment: It looks like the game's own markup language **not HTML**, which would explain why your created tag doesn't work.

Comment: Any chance the original creator used AngularJS?

Comment: I don't know, I'm not involved with the company yet, that's why I have to seek advice here

Comment: Adding to @mattytommo comment. There might an xsd file somewhere that should tell you all of the allowed elements.

Answer (score 0):

They're probably custom web components.

As described by [Rob Dodson on CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/modular-future-web-components/):

> Web Components are a collection of standards which are working their
>   way through the W3C and landing in browsers as we speak. In a
>   nutshell, they allow us to bundle markup and styles into custom HTML
>   elements. What's truly amazing about these new elements is that they
>   fully encapsulate all of their HTML and CSS. That means the styles
>   that you write always render as you intended, and your HTML is safe
>   from the prying eyes of external JavaScript.

You can find out more here: http://webcomponents.org/